# why the oldvalue is same to the new value in the vue3 Watch,

Tags: vuejs3, watch

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { ref, reactive, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'

    interface address {
      nation: string
    }

    interface basketballPlayer {
      name: string
      age: number
      address: address
    }

    let str = ref<string>('jth')
    let basketballPlayer = ref<basketballPlayer>({
      name: 'jokic',
      age: 28,
      address: {
        nation: 'Seriba',
      },
    })

    const handleClick = (): void => {
      str.value = 'Eric'
      basketballPlayer.value.address.nation = 'americal'
    }

    watch(
      [str, basketballPlayer],
      (newVal, oldVal) => {
        console.log(newVal, oldVal)
      },
      {
        // immediate: true,
        deep: true,
      }
    )
    </script>

    <template>
      <div>
        watch
        <a-button type="primary" @click="handleClick">更改</a-button>
      </div>
    </template>

    <style scoped></style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r1zy.png)
I define a object,and it has a deep structure,when i clike the button,and modified the address's nation,the console bar shows that,the two object has the same data,old value is same to new value,why

Answer (score 1):

In the [doc](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch), they have mentioned it:

> Note in deep mode, the new value and the old will be the **same object**
> if the callback was triggered by a deep mutation.

If you want to see the difference, you have to use a `getter`

```
watch(
  () => basketballPlayer.value.address.nation,
  (oldVal, newVal) => {
    console.log('oldVal', oldVal);
    console.log('newVal', newVal);
  }
);
```